# IMG Align with word-wrap issue?

Tags: html, css, alignment, word-wrap

Please look at my code on this jsfiddle. Why is the text not wrapping around the image? I have the wordbreak code in there. Did I put it in the wrong place or what?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwUXk/)

Is use these two word wraps inside my code, as far as I know...

```
style="word-wrap: break-all;"

style="word-wrap: break-word;"
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle HTML is invalid, you have elements like `<repeater>` as well as presentational markup (such as `align="left"`). Clean up your HTML and move all of your styles to a CSS file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made an example for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/HBsxK/1/

There are green and red paragraphs with an image. Both are the same, but the text is different inside paragraphs.

Upper one (green) is the one you mean?

The lower one has the same problem as with your fiddle: the text has no word breaks (spaces) and it has no meaningful words (how the browser knows, how to hyphenate or break in meaningful way something like "dgkl;fgdkl;fdgkl;fgdk;fdgk;dfgskljfdgjkldfgk;dfgsk;dfgskfdgkfgdkl;fgjd;flkgjdfgdfgsdfgjkdfgjdfgdfgdfgjfdgsjf" because human cannot know).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your desire to wrap text completely around the image, I don't see how this is possible. You either float the image left or right. Unfortunately there isn't a float: center to make your layout look more 'magazine-like'. You would need to split the text into two and and re-code as like here: http://www.alistapart.com/d/crosscolumn/example4.html

Comment: that is not what i am aiming for...the image is the the left, the title is no top, and the text it to the right, then drops below the image